# What is a proper word for time slowing down

Tags: meaning

I've been trying to figure our a proper single word for the phenomenon of time slowing down . Is there any such word ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "wot Einsten went on about", it's "time dilation".

But. It could be you mean this: During moments of intense action or panic or disaster, some people assert that your perception of time seems to "slow down". I have no idea, and don't care, whether this is scientifically true; it's commonplace in books, etc, to have descriptions like...

> Cut away, I had learned in practice. I'm supposed to cut away from the
> main canopy now and deploy the reserve from my chest-pack. Is this
> fair, a parachute failure on my twenty-ninth jump? I don't think this
> is fair! Mind uncontrolled. No discipline. D-minus. It was just my
> luck, then, that time slowed down. A second took a minute to pass. Yet
> why is it so hard to get my hands up to the release-latches and cut
> away from the wreck of the canopy? My hands weighed tons, and I inched
> them slow-motion to the latches at my shoulders, an enormous effort.

"Bridge across forever", Richard Bach

indeed, apparently military troops and the like - people who Face Danger - will talk about this effect as a matter of course, in their training and so on, and there's a word for it.

The only reason I know this, I was reading a Richard Marcinko thriller years ago and he explains it

## Tachypsychia

[image]

"Seal force Alpha", Richard Marcinko

Eg, [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRf_lpGpvhs) usage, [example](http://beforeitsnews.com/survival/2013/01/smart-survival-dealing-with-and-overcoming-tachypsychia-2457212.html) usage

I can only find a comic online psychological dictionary .. http://psychologydictionary.org/tachypsychia/

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 3):

The first (and so far) only connotation I get for *time slowing down* is in the context of the **theory of relativity**.

In that theory, there is a phenomenon called [**time dilation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation), which describes a relativistic observed time interval delta t' in a system moving relative to the observer with speed v as:

> delta t' = delta t / sqrt( 1 - (v<sup>2</sup>/c<sup>2</sup>))

Comment: I was taught the word was _dilatation_, but my lecturer admitted he was "rather old-fashioned".